# Telegram Client API. How to find channel/user?

Tags: node.js, telegram

I didn't see a findChannel method in the documentation.

Is there something like api.telegram.org/findchannel?token=MYTOKEN&query=channelName.

I also searched for a javascript library but I couldn't find one.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686463/how-to-get-user-id-of-a-phone-number-in-telegram

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get user\_id of a phone number in telegram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686463/how-to-get-user-id-of-a-phone-number-in-telegram)

Answer (score -1):

> I didn't find anything about problem in documentation.

What did you mean by this? I guess you meant that you didn't find anything related to the the problem you faced in the docs.

To answer your other questions for now there is no method in Telegram's API for finding channels.

And also I guess you are looking for Javascript (Node.js) libraries for working Telegram bots. There lots of them but this are the ones specifically mentioned in the [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples#node-js)

[**Telegraf**](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf). Full Telegram Bot API support, including games and inline mode.

[**Telebot**](https://github.com/kosmodrey/telebot). Easy way to write Telegram bots.

[**Botgram**](https://github.com/jmendeth/node-botgram). Microframework to build Telegram bots.

[**Telegram-node-bot**](https://github.com/naltox/telegram-node-bot). A node.js module.

[**Node-Telegram-bot**](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api). A node.js module.

[**Slimbot**](https://github.com/edisonchee/slimbot). A fuss-free, thin wrapper around Telegram Bot API for Node.js. No frills.