# get telegram user_id by phone number in TDlib

Tags: telegram, tdlib

I need to get user_id by phone number in Telegram using tdlib, I have tried [addContact](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1add_contact.html) and [importContacts](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1import_contacts.html), supposedly, they don't work for this purpose, and there is an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686463/how-to-get-user-id-of-a-phone-number-in-telegram/41696457#41696457) that doesn't work anymore. so, how would you get someones's user_id by phone contact info?

Answer (score 0):

Works on 5th of Jan 2021

```
auto contact = td_api::make_object<td_api::contact>();
contact->phone_number_ = "70000000000";
auto contacts = td_api::make_object<td_api::importContacts>();
contacts->contacts_.emplace_back(std::move(contact));

send_query(std::move(contacts),
  [](Object object) {
    if (object->get_id() == td_api::error::ID) {
      return;
    }
  auto imported_contancs = td::move_tl_object_as<td_api::importedContacts>(object);
  for (auto uid : imported_contancs->user_ids_) {
    std::cout << "uid: " << uid << std::endl;
  }
  });
```

Needless to say, you have to have updates in place, but for this you can use Client instance example published as a documentation part.